# cakePHP 1.3 select types with same value but dissimilar text

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

i want something like below:

```
<select>
<option value="">Select...</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="1">2</option>
<option value="1">3</option>
</select>
```

i used an array for options of the select type but the array doesn't let me have an array with same index (which is value)

```
echo $this->Form->input('something', array('options'=>$array));
```

Comment: can you please elaborate?

Comment: why not `<option value="1">1, 2, 3</option>` since it would have the same result without the overhead of additional rows here.

Comment: i need this for timezone selection on user signup. i cant go for <option value="1">1, 2, 3</option> because the list of tinezones for a specific time zone would extend the screen beyond view and it will not be very user friendly

Comment: ok i solved it using manual for loop, didn't want to use it but had to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not create an array like:

```
array(1 => 1, 1 => 2, 1 => 3);
```

So just make it manually.

```
<select name="data[something]" id="something">
    <option value="">Select...</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="1">2</option>
    <option value="1">3</option>
</select>
```

Or make it the usual way and use something like jquery

```
$('select').on('change', function() {
    $(this).val(1);
});
```

Comment: please read the question properly, i do not want different values

Comment: yes i made it manually, if you get any other ways please let me know for future reference. Anyways, thanks for your response.